# How to Launch app "Microsoft Company Portal" from the command line cmd.exe

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface, appx

How to Launch app "Microsoft Company Portal" from the command line cmd.exe

I'm working on a batch file that performs an on demand Company Portal Sync via PowerShell, but I'd like to open Company Portal from the batch file as an option.

Is there a CLI or PowerShell command that will launch Company Portal for the user?

Thank you.

[SOLVED]
I was missing keywords from my search. MS Company Portal is not a traditional executable but a ["Universal Windows Platform (UWP)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide) app.

A search for "How to open UWP apps from the command line" gave me the solution I was looking for.

Thank you to those who contributed comments.

Comment: That's a Microsoft Store app right? Try this site: https://www.auslogics.com/en/articles/how-to-open-microsoft-store-apps-from-command-prompt/

Comment: @mklement0  I think that if someone knows that Company Portal is a "Store App" then they would be able to google it without asking for assistance. Problem solved for me.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, all you needed to know is that the application at hand is a Microsoft Store application, with a subsequent web search leading you to a solution. Fortunately, future readers are now spared that second step, as they just need to navigate to the linked duplicate and will find concrete guidance - which is helpful, because discovering how to launch a given Microsoft Store application is far from trivial.